# PHP pdf file opened in chrome browser

Tags: php, google-chrome

I have a script that merges 2 documents and then it shows a final document in a browser.

It works in Firefox, Opera and IE. But it does not work in Chrome.
Chrome only shows loading and it stops in 1/4 of loading.

The code:

```
exec("pdftk A=$pdfin B=$tmpfname cat B1 A output $tmpfoutput");
$data = file_get_contents($tmpfoutput);
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-disposition: inline;filename=GeneratedPdf.pdf");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($tmpfoutput));
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
echo $data;
```

I have been told that it also worked in Chrome before so I think there will be only a problem with the last version.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By appending `Accept-Ranges: bytes`, your script tells the browser that it will accept range requests, i.e. multiple requests that request a part of the response. Your script obviously does not support range requests because it generates and provides the data at once.

To fix the error, remove `header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');`

If your PDF files are usually large, then a more user-friendly solution is to actually implement range requests in your script. Odds are that your server does already have an efficient routine that handles range requests, so a smart choice is to save PDF file to a publicly accessible directory, then 302-redirect the request to this URL after the PDF has been generated. Make sure that the URLs are unguessable, e.g. by using UUIDs. And remove the PDF files at some point, e.g. using a cronjob.